# GIO: get_icon() always returns None

Tags: gtk, python-3.x, gio

According to the GIO Documentation, it is possible to get the Icon of a file through g_file_info_get_icon ()
http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileInfo.html#g-file-info-get-icon

But this doesnt work, take a look at this sample:

```
print(somefile) # <FileInfo object at 0x17bf820 (GFileInfo at 0x1b15d00)> 
icon = somefile.get_icon()
print(icon) # always None
if icon is Gio.Icon: 
    print("isicon") # never happens
```

I've testet it with my whole home folder, get_icon() does ALWAYS return None. Did i made any mistakes or is this function simply not working with python / pygobject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you [query_info](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/GFile.html#g-file-query-info) the [standard::icon](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFileInfo.html#G-FILE-ATTRIBUTE-STANDARD-ICON%3aCAPS) attribute? For example,

```
f = File.new_for_commandline_arg('...')
info = f.query_info('standard::icon')
print(info.get_icon())
```